# Confusion about the order of a B spline

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, curves, spline

I am reading the wiki page on [b splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) and I am very confused about the order.

In particular the page states: "A spline of order {\displaystyle n}n is a piecewise polynomial function of degree {\displaystyle n-1}n-1 in a variable {\displaystyle x}x"

However their indexing of n goes up to 0, which would imply a curve with degree -1 which doesn't make any sense to me since the degree of a curve should be a non negative number.

[image]

Can someone clarify this for me? are they accidentally mixing degree and order and the indices of the spline notation should denote the degree, not the order?

Comment: Where did you see indexing goes up to 0?

Comment: Added a screenshot, the indexing of the order (i.e the second index in the spline notation) goes to 0, but in the prior paragraph that index was $n$, which denotes the order, not the degree.

Comment: It looks to me degree starts at 0 and order starts at 1.  In the past, when working with splines, I always used degree in the description.  I never encountered order as described in the reference.

Comment: I think it is just a typo. The definition for Bi,1(x) is defined correctly in the "Definition" section of that Wiki page.